# What does $dir =~ s/\n// means? I need help in explaining it in a simple way to understand

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to understand a perl code and I need a detail understanding on what this line means.

```
$dir =~ s/\n//
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`=~` is the binding operator; it tells certain operations (matching, substitution, transliteration) what their operand is.  So `$dir =~ s` is doing a substitution on the variable `$dir`.

`s/.../.../` is a substitution operation; the left part is a regular expression to match and the right part is an interpolated string to use to replace what was matched.  In your case, you are matching a single newline character and replacing it with nothing.

So your code basically removes the first newline from `$dir`, or, if there is no newline, does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
$dir =~ s/\n//
```

LHS (Left-Hand Side) is variable containing value that would become the pattern space

> =~

is regular expression binding operator, functions as equality test and assignment, varies slightly depends on RHS (Right-Hand Side) regex command which in this case is s (substitute)

RHS is regex command / expression

`pattern space` is any space for string upon which the regex would be applied in the context.

If e.g;

> $dir

variable contains `data` upon which the pattern:

> /\n/

would be applied (the actual pattern is `\n`, the '///' or '//' pair is only a placeholder to be recognized by language compiler). If it's true (T) i.e. matched/found, then a substitution will be performed, here the substitution is none, means it will simply clear it then assigned result to LHS, otherwise leave it LHS intact.
this pattern usually applied upon multi lines which inherently contains newline **\n** token as the line delimiter that can be detected and controlled by regex engine, but is invisible entity output except making next character at the line below.
Assuming $dir within multi lines, so $dir, ie. pattern space is **data\n** and in final $dir become **data**